# Google Analytics code be added to a template which I am not using?

Tags: google-analytics

Want to implement Google Analytics code to our website. Is it possible to add the code into any template or the one that is default. The reason is it is easy for me to add Google Analytics code to Beez3 template but for a template by Gavick.com, there is a different method. So, my question is if I add the code to Beez template which I am not using, will it work?

Answer (score 1):

No, it will not work. Only the template you have selected as default will be used. All other templates are ignored. I believe Gavic Pro have their own methods for using Google Analytics and the documentation on how to implement it can be seen at the following link:

https://www.gavick.com/documentation/uncategorized/how-to-add-google-analytics-or-other-statistics-in-joomla/

If you do decide to go along with editing the core template file as shown in the documentation link above, then you will need to make sure you re-implement the code if you ever update the template as your changes will be lost.

Answer (score 1):

Might I suggest a plugin - you can just install and enable it for your whole site, then it doesn't matter which template you're using at all.

At the Extensions Directory, there's quite a selection under [SITE ANALYTICS - GOOGLE BASED](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/site-management/analytics/site-analytics-google-based).